# Shorthand for long function name

Tags: python

I have a function named `cached_classproperty()`.
That function makes a caching descriptor accessible via class.

```
def cached_classproperty(timeout=None):
    class Inner(object):
        def __init__(self, function):
            self.function = function

        def __get__(self, inst, cls):
            if cache_key not in cache:
                cache[cache_key] = self.function(cls)
            return cache[cache_key]

    return Inner
```

Prefix `cached_` is required for that function.

How to name function `cached_classproperty()` shorter and cleaner?

Comment: By writing a name that has less characters... I do not get what you expect us to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign function reference to a variable like:

```
a = cached_classproperty
```

then call it like:

```
a()
```